# Outlook AddIn: creating new ContactItem

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I use the following code to assign some data to an appropriate ContactItem (Sender) of given MailItem. If Sender.GetContact() returns null, I'm trying to create a new ContactItem.

```
        Outlook.MailItem myItem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.OutlookItem;            
        Outlook.ContactItem currentContact = myItem.Sender.GetContact();
        if (currentContact != null)
        {
            currentContact.Body = "Example";
            currentContact.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            currentContact = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem) as Outlook.ContactItem;
            currentContact.Email1DisplayName = myItem.SenderName;
            currentContact.Email1Address = myItem.SenderEmailAddress;
            currentContact.Email1AddressType = myItem.SenderEmailType;
            currentContact.Body = "Example";
            currentContact.Save();                
        }
```

But this does not seem to work fine for me. The next time I'm getting the contact of that MailItem (see the following code), it returns null. Again. And again.

```
        Outlook.MailItem myItem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.OutlookItem;            
        Outlook.ContactItem currentContact = myItem.Sender.GetContact();
```

Is there something wrong? It seems like that new ContactItem is not assigned to Sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetContact will return ContactItem object only if the outgoing message (does not work for incoming) had the contact explicitly added  as a recipient.

GetContact will ***not*** check if you happen to have a contact item with the same email address.

If you need to find a matching contact, explicitly use MAPIFolder.Items.Find on the Contacts folder.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But GetContact definetely works for _some_ incoming messages.

Comment: That depends on how the message was sent. Generally, you will have one-off entry ids for recipients and GetContact will not work.